# Erlang - how to "unflatten" an array

Tags: arrays, matrix, erlang, tuples

I'm new to Erlang, so this question might be a little basic.
I got an array with N^2 elements (I know N) which I want to break down into an array (or tuple, doesn't matter) with N tuples, each with N elements.

i.e: I want to turn:

> [14,20,26,20,29,38,26,38,50]
>   into:
>   [  {14,20,26} , {20,29,38} , {26,38,50} }

Is there a simple way or a function that does this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it won't let me edit or delete the question.  
'matFormat (Acc, [],_)->lists:reverse( Acc);  
matFormat (Acc, Mat ,N)->  
 {H,T} =  lists:split(N, Mat),  
 matFormat ([list_to_tuple(H)|Acc], T ,N ).'

Answer (score 5):

Use pattern matching:

```
s([X, Y, Z | Next]) ->
   [{X, Y, Z} | s(Next)];
s([]) -> [].
```

This will fail if you don't supply a multiple of 3 elements, but that is probably what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The size of the tuples changes according to user's input... It's not always 3.

Comment: You can fix that by using `lists:split(K, L)` where `K` is the users input of where to split. You also need `list_to_tuple/1` and the same recursion as above.

Answer (score 0):

this should do what you want.

```
s(L,N) -> s(L,N,[]).

s([],_,R) -> lists:reverse;
s(L,N,R) ->
    {L1,L2} = lists:split(N,L),
    s(L2,[list_to_tuple(L1)|R]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function `sublist(List1, Start, Len) -> List2`,

> Returns the sub-list of List1 starting at Start and with (max) Len
>   elements. It is not an error for Start+Len to exceed the length of the
>   list.

```
unflatten(L, N) ->
    case N*N == length(L) of
        true -> unflatten_help(L, 1, N, []);
        false ->
            {error, "wrong list length!"}
    end.

unflatten_help(_L, Start, N, Res) when Start == (N*N + 1) ->
    lists:reverse(Res);
unflatten_help(L, Start, N, Res) ->
    Temp = lists:sublist(L, Start, N),
    unflatten_help(L, Start + N, N, [Temp | Res]). 


main() ->
    L = [14,20,26,20,29,38,26,38,50],
    unflatten(L, 3).
```

The output:

> [[14,20,26],[20,29,38],[26,38,50]]

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code is fine for you:

```
array_to_tuples([],_) -> [];
array_to_tuples(L,N) ->
    {L1,L2} = lists:split(N,L),
    [list_to_tuple(L1)|array_to_tuples(L2,N)].
```

This will split your array, considering N*2 elements, in N tuples.